# Run a python script as part of its parent module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python project structured like this:

```
root/
    __init__.py
    coolstuff.py
    moduleA/
        __init__.py
        myscript.py
```

**When my working directory is** `moduleA`, how can I run `myscript.py`, knowing that it needs to have access to `coolstuff` ?

**EDIT**: I am aware of the `$PYTHONPATH` solution but I would like to know which other solutions exist

Comment: you can add your root directory to $PYTHONPATH & you can then import coolstuff module anywhere..

Comment: here's your naswer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python

Comment: @shiva your answer doesn't take into account the fact that I want to run `myscript` from the working directory `moduleA`; doing so will either get me an `Attempted relative import in non-package` or a `Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

Comment: @advay.umare feel free to put your comment as an answer as I think it could still be of use to other people

Comment: @FlorentinHennecker OKZZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your root directory to path and import your package. Include the following code in myscript.py.

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname,abspath
sys.path.append(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))))
import coolstuff
# do cool stuff
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: added import sys

Comment: Ah, interesting answer! There is still one thing that bothers me about it though; this solution requires you to know where you are in the hierarchy. Would there be a way to do this by defining `root` as the top-level package and avoid doing a hardcoded number of `dirname`s ?

Comment: I have no knowledge of such solution, but I don't see a problem in knowing the hierarchy of your own project and including 3 rules at the top of your scripts.

Comment: If by run you mean to execute so that it's its own `__main__` then no, I do not think so. See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references. Esp. last paragraph.

In other words. Directly executed script has no knowledge of a package the directory structure may suggest it is being part of.

Answer (score 0):

You can import sys and import the actual directory where your coolstuff.py exist.

Eg:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/root")
import coolstuff
```

**Note**: If you are using Windows use the path like this - "C:\Users\test\Documents" (Considering your coolstuff.py is residing in Documents)

```
__init__.py is not required for this method.
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

Add path of your project to PYTHONPATH :

```
export PYTHONPATH =$PYTHONPATH:/xyz/root/
```

or from python like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/xyz/root/")# path to your project directory
```

Now you can access all the module from your root directory by simply impporting.